# Thunderbird: Your message was sent but a copy was not placed in your sent folder

Tags: thunderbird

So I've been getting this error using Thunderbird with my Gmail account when trying to send emails:

```
Thunderbird: Your message was sent but a copy was not placed in your sent folder (Sent) due to network or file access errors. You can retry or save the message locally to Local Folders/Sent-
```

This is actually happening with all my Mail accounts and not just Thunderbird...

---

Things I have tried:

1. I changed the connection security on server settings from STARTTLS to SSL/TLS.
2. I tried changing THUNDERBIRD preferences editor security.tls.version.min from 3 to 1

---

Both didn't seem to work for me. Anyone have the same problem and found a solution to this?

Comment: I'm having the same problem on all 3 e-mail accounts on one computer but the same 3 e-mail accounts work fine on another.

I'm not using gmail but rather e-mail accounts from a domain hosting company. They are imap. I've poured through the settings on both machines and they are the same.

I've also tried deleting the passwords and going into troubleshooting mode. Nothing has worked.

Answer (score 2):

Help menu -> turn troubleshoot mode on

this will disable all your addons and restart thunderbird in troubleshoot mode on.

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This long living and widespread problem seems to be linked to the inability of the hard disk to service multiple requests to read/write large mailbox files. I have resolved the issue by installing faster disk with 8x bigger cache size.

Answer (score 0):

go to settings /passwords/ note both SMTP and IMAP passwords , delete the registered passwords, restart Thunderbird enter the password again IMAP, then create a message Send it , it will prompt for SMTP password, enter it. That's it, it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I just reconfigured "**Copies & Folders**"

When sending messages, automatically:

Place a copy in:

(and selected **"Sent" Folder on**:)

Previously "Other" was selected (and worked just fine...)

This happened from one day to the other, with no update from Thunderbird... this is very very strange!

Comment: Best solution for me was changing my email client to Spark! :D

Comment: worked for me, for some reason my send folder was within an inbox folder, changed to it, and now everything works fine ! thx !